# Would it be appropriate to compare knn and cnn algorithm for facial recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, k-nearest-neighbour

I wanna compare these two algorithms but I'm not sure whether I should and also what parameters to keep in mind if I do ? what should I consider if I do go forward apart from the same data set of images?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare recognition rates, you will always get a difference, and thus should test the difference for statistical significance with an appropriate test. As you have paired data for each test image, and as the output is binary (recognition is right or wrong), a McNemar test should be appropriate.

Note that both kNN and CNN depend on a number of parameters, and you should optimize these parameters on a different set than the test set.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the parameters part please? what are the parameters ? and what parameters should i change so that the algorithms come close to each other?

Comment: The obvious parameters of kNN are *k* and the distance metric, where distances are usually computed on standardized features. Less obvious parameters are feature weights, where binary wheights mean feature selection. As a simple optimization criterion, the leavo-one-out error rate on the trainng data can be used. Neural networks have the layer layout as a "parameter". As optimizing it with leave-one-out is computationally prohibitive, you could use k-fold cross-validation.